# Vuex Get State After Mutation in components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I am very new to state management and I got stuck in one position. Any help will be highly appreciated.

I have my store setup as:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default function() {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {},

state: {
      isAdmin: false,
},

mutations: {
      changeAuthStatus(state, authStatus) {
        state.isAdmin = authStatus;
        console.log(state.isAdmin) //output: true
      }
},
actions: {
      changeAuthStatus({ commit }, authStatus) {
        commit("changeAuthStatus", authStatus);
      }
}

 });
  return Store;
 }
```

Before Entering to any route my route-guard will check if the user is 'Admin' or not and display the options in component accordingly.

My route guard is setup as:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

import $store from "../store/index";
const store = $store();

let adminStatus = store.state.isAdmin;

const requireAuth = (to, from, next) => {
    adminStatus = true;
    store.dispatch("changeAuthStatus", authStatus);  
  }
  if (adminStatus) {
    next();
  } else next({ name: "Home" });
};

const routes=[
{
 {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: () => import("components/Home.vue")
  },
    path: "/add/",
    name: "AddPost",
    beforeEnter: requireAuth,
    component: () => import("components/AddPost.vue")
  }
]

export default function(){
const Router = new VueRouter({routes});

  return Router;
}
```

And my 'AddPost.vue' component is setup as:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div v-if="$store.state.isAdmin">
    <h1>Welcome Admin </h1>
    </div>
    
    <div v-else> Welcome Guest </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
created(){
   console.log(this.$store.state.isAdmin); //output: false
}
}
</script>
```

On a positive response from server the state in vuex-store is mutating successfully to "isAdmin:true" but the component is not getting the updated status. I don't know what I am doing wrong. How can I solve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export a store object instead of a function.  Otherwise the store that you pass to the Vue app in *main.js* (providing it to components)  will not be the same store that you use in your route guard.

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {},
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  strict: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a getter in the store which will return the state of `isAdmin` and then use the getter to fetch the value in your component from the store.

Comment: Did that, and it is still the same.

Comment: If `$store.state.<somevalue>` has a value, a getter returning that value won't change anything

Comment: I can see 'true' in the 'console.log in commit (mutation)'. But the component is always getting 'false'.